# Obter valores dos campos de um NSArray com conteudo CoreData

Tags: array, ios, swift, xcode

Eu tenho uma tabela em `coredata` com alguns campos, eu consigo obter o tamanho destes valores mas eu necessito dos valores de cada campo, eu tenho este código:

```
var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Radar") //my table in coredata

let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

println(results.count) //this is the count that i can do
```

Mas eu preciso de mais, `Radar` tem estes campos: `Desc`, `Lat`, `Long` e eu preciso dos seus valores para criar um `Annotation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, para quem precisar aqui vai:

```
if results.count > 0
{
    for result in results
    {
         if let r = result as? Radar{
             //now you can access the properties of Radar in r
             println(r.descr)
         } else{
             println("Could not cast fetch result to Radar")
         }
    }   
}
```

Comment: você pode aceitar sua própria resposta.